# Improve Performance of React Initial Page Load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, vite

I want to improve the initial load of page of my react application . Currently as checked I see that content download is taking time while loading the page and then my page is loading .
The performance gets worse with poor network connection .
What are the different ways(Apart from just improving the content download) in which I can improve the performance of my page load.
I am using Vite as my bundler , so wanted to ask if any settings/configuration in Vite that can improve the performance.

1. Firstly I tried code splitting and created chunks according to the routes . This didn't impact much on the performance . Also I see multiple chunks created of the packages of node modules that I have used . If I remove manual chunking from node modules folder . It created one Big JS file of more than 8MB , If I keep manual chunking of node modules , it creates multiple JS files (around 30 of some KB each) . I am confused which strategy will be better.
2. I have tried service worker to try and cache static assets , it does cache the assets in the browser but hasn't impacted the performance that much , also I am not sure how it will get the latest version in case the any asset is updated.

Comment: "Big JS file of more than 8MB" 8 *megabytes* of JS?!?!?!? That's double the length of the famously long novel *War and Peace*....

Comment: Use a bundle explorer to analyze your JS bundle, you are almost certainly doing things like importing multiple versions of the same libraries, importing things you don't actually use, using multiple different libraries that do the same thing (e.g. moment **and** date-fns), etc etc. I work on a huge React ecommerce app (hundreds of frontend devs contributing at any given time) and our initial page load is 400 *kilobytes* of JS (which is 1/200th the size of what you're talking about).

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, I am thinking now in this direction, but 1 question how do you deal with node modules bundled size ? Do you divide them into smaller chunks as well ? Do you dynamically import them ? My applications total JS size is just 800kb which I have further divided into chunks ,it's the node modules size that troubles me

Comment: I guess what I am really trying to say is that there is *no way* your app actually needs 8 MB of JS and there's a very good chance that your app isn't even using some of that at all. Pick the low-hanging fruit first: get rid of everything you're not using. Deduplicate multiple versions of the same thing (e.g. you have multiple versions of lodash in your bundle). Deduplicate libraries that do similar things (don't need moment *and* date-fns, lodash *and* underscore, React *and* jquery, etc). Swap out heavyweights (e.g. moment) for slimmer alternatives (date-fns). Make sure you are tree-shaking

Comment: ...to eliminate dead code. *Then* (and only then) should you start thinking about bundle-splitting, lazy loading, etc. Because if you don't do the other things *first*, you're just delaying the pain instead of treating the illness. As for the rest we have it split to get it down, generally by route (with some exceptions). But really, if you don't have 100+ people working on your app right this minute there is no reason you should even need to worry about bundle splitting, you should have < 1 MB JS for your *entire site*.